# Javascript Google Maps v3 marker becomes invisible when dragging is enabled

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using the Javascript Google Maps API v3 to make a map that builds a polygon point by point where the map is clicked. In addition, I want to make the markers that I position where the user clicked to be draggable to enable them to edit the shape of the polygon.

I followed this example: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/poly_edit.html
which is exactly what I want I want it to do.

My issue is that when I make the marker draggable it becomes invisible on the map.
I replicated the error in a jsbin, just uncomment the line that says marker.setDraggable(true) to see the error. http://jsbin.com/pekuyavi/9/edit?js,output

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that root cause of this problem is definition of map. You used:

```
    position: latLng,
```

instead of

```
    center: latLng,
```

Why this delete the marker when `marker.setDraggable()` is called I cannot figure out. Marker is deleted even if marker click event handler is commented out!

**Update:** even just commenting out `position: latLng,` from map options will work because map center is set later using `map.panTo(latLng);`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!
I'd upvote as well, but I don't have the reputation for it

Answer (score -1):

u can set property like this to the marker

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      title:'anytext'
  });
```

and u can remove the below metioned code bcoz that removes the marker from ur layer

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      marker.setMap(null);
      for (var i=0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; i++);
      markers.splice(i, 1);
      path.removeAt(i);
    });
```

Comment: That's all good, but that doesn't affect to the visibility of the marker. http://jsbin.com/pekuyavi/10/edit?js,output

Comment: This is not good answer. Just setting marker as draggable should not trigger click event on marker.

Answer (score -1):

**try this one**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//   Initialize map
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8142026, 144.963785);  
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    center: latLng,
    scaleControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);




//   set up polygon creation
  var markers = [],
      path = new google.maps.MVCArray,
      poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#555FF'
      });

  poly.setMap(map);
  poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {


    var maker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: evt.latLng,
      map: map,
      draggable: true

    });

    markers.push(maker);

//     Add marker dragend listener to move the path to the marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(maker, 'dragend', function () {
      for (var i=0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != maker; i++);
      path.setAt(i, maker.getPosition());
    });
    path.insertAt(path.length, evt.latLng);
  });



});
```